# How to map kafka topic names and respective records in spark streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am streaming fro kafka topic like below;

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = 
    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
                                  String.class, 
                                  String.class,
                                  StringDecoder.class,
                                  StringDecoder.class,
                                  kafkaParams, 
                                  topicSet);

directKafkaStream.print();
```

The output gives like below for one topic:

```
(null,"04/15/2015","18:44:14")
(null,"04/15/2015","18:44:15")
(null,"04/15/2015","18:44:16")
(null,"04/15/2015","18:44:17")
```

How do I map topic name and records.
ex: topic is "callData" ,it should something like below and so on

```
(callData,"04/15/2015","18:44:14")
(callData,"04/15/2015","18:44:15")
(callData,"04/15/2015","18:44:16")
(callData,"04/15/2015","18:44:17")
```

Comment: What does *"map topic name and records"* mean?

Comment: just updated the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I map topic name and records?

In order to extract the partition information, [you'll need to use the overload which accepts a `Function` receiving `MessageAndMetadata<K, V>`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$) and returning the type you wish to transform to.

It looks like this:

```
Map<TopicAndPartition, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(new TopicAndPartition("topicname", 0), 1L);

JavaInputDStream<Map.Entry> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
        javaContext,
        String.class,
        String.class,
        StringDecoder.class,
        StringDecoder.class,
        Map.Entry.class, // <--- This is the record return type from the transformation.
        kafkaParams,
        map,
        messageAndMetadata -> 
            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(messageAndMetadata.topic(),
                                          messageAndMetadata.message()));
```

Note I used `Map.Entry` as Java's replacement for a `Tuple2` in Scala. You can provide your own class which has a `Partition` and `Message` property as well and use the for the transformation. Note the type of the kafka input stream is now `JavaInputDStream<Map.Entry>`, as that is what the transformation is returning.

Comment: 16/05/31 10:44:20 ERROR kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream: ArrayBuffer(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set())

Comment: what should be the value of map here.It says  Map<TopicAndPartition, Long>.What should I put here

Comment: @Alka Should be the name of your queue, partition and offset, respectively. I've edited with an example.

Comment: awesome..Thanks...I need one more info..As I am new to spark..From where I do get these information about spark.which api to use at what place.

Comment: @Alka It's alot about trail and error. You have the [Spark API Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.package) and the [Spark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) at your disposal. If you have another question, I suggest you open a new question.